# What's the type of `{ "abc" }`

Tags: scala, types

Scala code:

```
{ "abc" }
```

What the type of it? Is it `=> String`, or just `String`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386127

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's worth saying that the type of the block is the type of its result expression.

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#blocks

More or less.

> The expected type of the final expression e is the expected type of
>   the block.

That's the case (obviously) for `f { "abc" }`.  You get conversions based on the param type to the function.

Answer (score 1):

It's a `String`

```
scala> { "abc" }
res0: String = abc
```

Comment: I can't pass `{ () => "abc" }` to a method `def print(s: => String)`, but can pass to `def hello(s: ()=> String)`

Comment: @Freewind that is compiler "magic", as explained in great details here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25409347/846273

Comment: `() => String` and `=> String` are different, so I don't understand why you conflate them.

Comment: @som-snytt they're roughly equivalent, however it's probably not accurate to treat them as they were the same. I'll take that bit away.