# Why `def hello[T](f: => T) = f; hello(()=>12)` is compilable but `def hello(f: => Int) = f; hello(()=>12)` is not?

Tags: scala, callbyname

Following code can be compiled:

```
def hello[T](f: => T) = f
hello(() => 12)
```

But following not:

```
def hello(f: => Int) = f
hello(() => 12)
```

Which reports error:

```
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : () => Int
 required: Int
                  hello(() => 12)
```

Why?

Answer (score 6):

I would say because `T` can be any `() => x`, but `Int` can't be a `() => x`.

In your situation you are passing `() => 12` as parameter which is a legal action because `T` has no constrains and can be anything, in fact doing so returns a partial applied function:

```
scala> def hello[T](f: => T) = f
hello: [T](f: => T)T

scala> hello(()=>12)
res1: () => Int = <function0>
```

That you can call so:

```
scala> res1()
res2: Int = 12
```

The second case instead you are passing a function from `Unit` to `Int` which is not an `Int` (it returns an `Int` but it's not an `Int`).

The fact that `f` is passed as call by name parameter doesn't make any difference here:

```
scala> def hello[T](f: T) = f
hello: [T](f: T)T

scala> hello(()=>12)
res11: () => Int = <function0>

scala> def hello(f: Int) = f
hello: (f: Int)Int

scala> hello(()=>12)
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : () => Int
 required: Int
              hello(()=>12)
```

Don't confuse this: `f: => T` with this: `f: () => T`, they are different things, to make it clear:

```
scala> def hello[T](f: () => T) = f
hello: [T](f: () => T)() => T

scala> hello(()=>12)
res13: () => Int = <function0>

scala> def hello(f: () => Int) = f
hello: (f: () => Int)() => Int

scala> hello(()=>12)
res14: () => Int = <function0>
```

Now it compile in both cases because `f` is a function from `Unit` to `T` in the first case (where `T` can of course be an `Int`) and in the second case `f` is a function from `Unit` to `Int` and you can pass `() => 12` as parameter.

Comment: "I may be wrong" - no, you're absolutely correct, that's exactly what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply due to the fact that `=> T` not being the same as `() => T`...

`=> T` is call by name, meaning

```
def hello(f: => Int) = f
```

Is supposed to be called like this:

```
hello(12)
```

The reason `def hello[T](f: => T) = f` works with `() => 12` is because you're putting in a `Function0[Int]` on T's spot, which is different from just an `Int`

To make the `() =>` syntax work as expected, consider doing this:

```
def hello(f: () => Int) = f // can also be written as:
def hello(f: Function0[Int]) = f
```

NOW your function *expects* a `Function0`, where it didn't before, and `hello(() => 12)` will work as expected